# Query for Bulk update in Mysql

Tags: mysql, bulkupdate

Consider the following table(T) in mysql.

```
id c1  c2
1  10  100
2  20  200
3  30  300
```

Suppose I want to update "c1" of the row with id=2. I can do the following.

```
UPDATE T set col1=20 where id=1;
```

Suppose I want bulk update.

```
INSERT INTO T(id,c1) VALUES (1,20),(2,40) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c1=VALUES(c1);
```

But this will give you an error if default value for "c2" is not set in the SCHEMA.

Is there another way to achieve the task?

Comment: @fancyPants  But the same gives me an error.

Comment: @fancyPants First it try to check if all the attributes are present before it check whether the id is duplicate.That is why I am getting the error. But I don't know why it is not giving error for you. are you using mysql?

Comment: Nevermind, didn't see that the error is actually for column c2.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens when you `INSERT` a value for the first time, meaning there's no duplicate key to update. Your c2 column is not nullable and has no default value. To fix this either

- make c2 nullable or
- provide a default value for c2 or
- provide a value for c2 in your insert statement

When you don't want to insert into the table, insert the values into a temporary table, then use an update statement and join the two tables.

Comment: Is there any better way to do this(without using insert)?

Comment: Added another comment in the answer.

Comment: Actually I need to optimise the bulk update and I don't think this is the way to optimise it.

Comment: I need to do it with just a single sql query. No joins.

Comment: This would be a single query. `update a join b on a.id=b.id set a.whatever = b.whatever;` What's the problem with that? You won't optimize it any further, when you don't want to insert whatever data you provide.